# create a dictionary with incrementing values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list and I want to generate a dictionary `d` taking out duplicates and excluding a single item, such that the first key has value 0, the second has value 1, and so on.

I have written the following code:

```
d = {}
i = 0
for l in a_list:
    if (l not in d) and (l != '<'):
        d[l] = i
        i += 1
```

If `a_list = ['a', 'b', '<', 'c', 'b', 'd']`, after running the code `d` contains `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd':3}`. Order is not important.
Is there a more elegant way to obtain the same result?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of what you expect based on a sample input?

Comment: It would really help clarify exactly what you are looking for if you could provide that sample input/output and clarify if order is required....

Comment: Is order required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{b: a for a, b in enumerate(set(a_list) - {'<'})}
```

`set(a_list)` creates a set from `a_list`.
That effectively strips duplicate numbers in `a_list`, as a `set` can only contain unique values.

Comment: This is elegant.  Nice idea to use set operations.

Answer (score 6):

Use `dict.fromkeys` to get your unique occurrences (minus values you don't want), then `.update` it to apply the sequence, eg:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', '<', 'c', 'b', 'd']

d = dict.fromkeys(el for el in a_list if el != '<')
d.update((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(d))
```

Gives you:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'd': 2, 'c': 3}
```

If order is important, then use `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys` to retain the ordering of the original values, or sort the unique values if they should be alphabetical instead.

Comment: You can generalize this with `if el not in "<"`.  Then is can apply to any string of blacklisted characters, e.g. `"<>{}["` etc.

Comment: if there are multiple backlisted chars I would rather use `set(a_list).difference(blacklisted_chars)` inside the `dict.fromkeys` than a `not in` in the comprehension (simply because it could have a much better runtime performance).

Comment: `d = dict.fromkeys(a_list)`, `d.remove('<')` avoids the list comprehension and evaluating the blacklisted char multiple times. Follow with the `d.update(...)`.

Comment: @IceArdor I see where you're going with that. Although, there's no list-comp - just a gen-exp - so that's not a big deal. There's no `dict.remove` method, so you'd have to use `del d['<']` and prepare for an exception where it's not present or use `d.pop('<', None)` instead. There's not much different for a single value whether it's filtered out first or left to be reduced to a single key in the dictionary and then removed. In the case of multi-values, the original can be changed to `if el not in "<>!@[]"` easily, but would then require N many key deletions afterwards with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

What is needed here is an ordereddict and to manually filter the list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()

new_list = []

a_list = [1,3,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1]

for i in a_list:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)

for i, a in enumerate(new_list):
    if a != "<":
       d[i] = a
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2)])
```

If original order is not important:

```
final_d = {i:a for i, a in enumerate(set(a_list)) if a != "<"}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention a further requirement, I edited the question

Comment: @AreTor fixed. Please see my recent edit. The code will not store "<" as a key in `d`.

Comment: This *still* produces different result than original code for `a_list=[1,3,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1]`

Comment: In what way is this more elegant than the original?

Comment: Where was it indicated that order is of importance?

Comment: @idjaw: It wasn't, but I'm pretty sure the set of keys in each should be the same.

Comment: @idjaw I thought it best to provide a solution where order was maintained, in case the OP's question required it but did not mention it. I will provide a solution where order is not necessary.

Comment: Stating example output w/o corresponding input is worse than useless.

Comment: The second solution with enumerate and set seems elegant to me, however it can be slower than a single for cycle like in my code, isn't it?

Comment: If `"<"` is not the last item, it and the index e.g. `0-3` will be ignored.  The conditional on the enumerate list may skip an index.

Answer (score 2):

I personally find recursion quite elegant, tail-recursion especially so:

```
def f( d, a_list ):
    if a_list:
        if a_list[0] not in d and a_list[0] != '<':
            d[a_list[0]] = len(d)            
        return f( d, a_list[1:] )
    else:
        return d
```

So that

```
f( {}, "acbcbabcbabcb" )
```

will yield

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

just like the original code does on the same input (modulo order of the keys).

Comment: I've seen so many variations of this solution, and this is the first time I've seen it done with recursion. Pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

If truly:

> Order is not important.

```
{k: i for i, k in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x not in "<", set(a_list)))}
# {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 2}
```

EDIT: @qnnnnez's answer takes advantage of set operations, giving an elegant version of the latter code.

Otherwise you can implement the `unique_everseen` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to preserve order.  For convenience, you can import it from a library that implements this recipe for you, i.e. `more_itertools`.

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

{k: i for i, k in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x not in "<", unique_everseen(a_list)))}
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```